# bash regex match or not

Tags: regex, bash, match

I created this regex:

```
'^CPU\s+LOAD\:\s+([0-9]{1,3})\s+Average\:\s+([0-9]{1,3}).?$'
```

to match and extract values from my string:

"CPU LOAD: 100 Average: 89"

but occasionally the values will not be available such as:

"CPU LOAD:  Average: 89"

"CPU LOAD: 100 Average: "

"CPU LOAD:  Average: "

and it will not match, but I need it as a place holder to return "" when values are not present.

So I have tried several things and I think this:

```
'^CPU\s+LOAD\:\s+([[0-9]{1,3}]?)\s+Average\:\s+([[0-9]{1,3}]?).?$'
```

should work, but it doesn't seem to be. Is this correct syntax?

This is my test code that wants to fail answer 1 I followed the link and it seems to work at the link page.

```
rx='^CPU\s+LOAD\:\s+(?:([0-9]{1,3})\s+)?Average:(?:\s+([0-9]{1,3}))?$'
line="CPU LOAD: 89 Average: 99"
  if [[ $line =~ $rx ]]; then
    printf "\n\n${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}\n\n"
  else
    printf "\n\nDidn't Match\n\n"
  fi
```

I updated

```
rx='^CPU\ +LOAD\:\ +(([0-9]{1,3})\ +)?Average:(\ +([0-9]{1,3}))?$'
```

and 
"CPU LOAD: 100 Average: 89" passes

"CPU LOAD:  Average: 89" passes

"CPU LOAD: 100 Average: " fails

The latest updates require me to:

```
 printf "\n\n${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}\n\n"
```

To capture everything and puts either single value into

```
${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Thanks for Forth Bird's help. This is the final code that works for my needs.

```
rx='^CPU\s+LOAD:\s+(([0-9]{1,3})\s+)?Average:(\s+([0-9]{1,3}))?.?$'
```

Comment: Which regex are you mentioning? Bash regex supports neither `\s` notation nor {n,m} quantifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might do is use an optional non capturing group:

`^CPU[[:blank:]]+LOAD\:[[:blank:]]+(([0-9]{1,3})[[:blank:]]+)?Average:([[:blank:]]+([0-9]{1,3}))?$`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wHHcuj/1)

You could match the space by escaping it or use `[[:blank:]]` to match a whitespace or a tab.

```
rx='^CPU[[:blank:]]+LOAD\:[[:blank:]]+(([0-9]{1,3})[[:blank:]]+)?Average:([[:blank:]]+([0-9]{1,3}))?$'
line="CPU LOAD: 89 Average: 99"
if [[ $line =~ $rx ]]; then
    printf "\n\n${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}\n\n"
else
    printf "\n\nDidn't Match\n\n"
fi
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/wWk0Jz)

Comment: I added some info. This didn't seem to work for me. I posted my test code.

Comment: I used the updated regex... it doesn't like the loss of the last value. I will try the [[:blank:]] approach... the [[:blank:]] treats the loss of the last value as a fail

Comment: Is it possible to have the missing values in ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} as blank or null? First value ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}  second value ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

Comment: @WesZ The "CPU LOAD: 100 Average: " fails because there is a space following the colon. You can match that with this [updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/QqQe3X/1) Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks The fourth bird for you help. I finally settles on this mean and lean version thanks to you. rx='^CPU\s+LOAD:\s+(([0-9]{1,3})\s+)?Average:(\s+([0-9]{1,3}))?.?$'